# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$id' (T_VARIABLE) in line 15

Tags: php

```
public function addData($name, $address, $fee) {
    $data = array("name" => $name, "address" => $address, "fee" => $fee);
    $id = $this->db->insert(array($this->table => $data));
```

What is the error on line 15

Comment: it is good if you add code instead of adding image.

Comment: public function addData($name, $address, $fee){
        $data = array(
            "name"          => $name,
            "address"       => $address,
            "fee"           => $fee
            );
        $id = $this->db->insert(array($this->table => $data));

Comment: I didn't get any parse error. I think you might including that outside the class

Answer (score 0):

Because you undefined variable.

```
public function addData($id, $name, $address, $fee){

}
```